# Animate elements with pure CSS toggles ( checkbox hack )

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

```js
document.querySelector( "style" ).innerHTML += `
  html { overflow: hidden; font-size: 5.5vmin; user-select: none; }
  html, table, caption, th, td, p {
    margin: 0; padding: 1rem;
    border-bottom-style: solid; border-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #fbfbfb; color: #444;
    text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  html, table, caption, caption p, thead, thead p, td p {
    border-style: none; background-color: transparent;
  }
  html { font-family: Arial; }
  [ type="checkbox" ] { display: none; }
  table {
    position: relative; top: -2rem;
    width: 100%; max-width: 40rem;
    margin: 1rem auto;
  }
  caption p, thead th, thead p {
    border-style: none; background-color: #f7f7f7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  caption, caption p {
    padding: 0 1rem; background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
  }
  #clear thead p { color: #444; }
  th:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem; }
  th:last-child { border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem; }
`;
```

```css
td, p {
  color: #555; cursor: default;
  transition-property: border-color, color, font-size, letter-spacing;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
tr:hover td { border-color: #eee; }
tfoot td:first-child { border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem; }
tfoot td:last-child { border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem; }
tr p:hover { color: #000; }
[ for="tog" ], [ for="tog" ]::after {
  position: absolute; top: 1rem; left: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 7rem; height: 4rem;
  margin: 1rem; background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 4rem; content: ""; cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: left, background-color; transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
[ for="tog" ]::after {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  transform: scale( 0.7 ); margin: 0;
  width: 4rem; background-color: #eee;
}
#tog:checked ~ main [ for="tog" ]::after {
  left: 3rem; background-color: #ddd;
}
#tog:checked ~ main [ for="tog" ] { background-color: #444; }
#dark { display: none; }
#tog:checked ~ main #clear { display: none; }
#tog:checked ~ main #dark { display: table; }
#dark th, #dark th p { background-color: #222; color: #f5f5f5; }
#dark tfoot td { background-color: #f5f5f5; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="tog">
<main>
  <div class="tog_wrap"> <label for="tog"></label> </div>
  <table id="clear">
    <caption> <p> table </p> </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> <p>one</p> </th> <th> <p>two</p> </th> <th> <p>three</p> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td> <p>four</p> </td> <td> <p>five</p> </td> <td> <p>six</p> </td>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <td> <p>seven</p> </td> <td> <p>eight</p> </td> <td> <p>nine</p> </td>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <table id="dark">
    <caption> <p> table </p> </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> <p>one</p> </th> <th> <p>two</p> </th> <th> <p>three</p> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td> <p>four</p> </td> <td> <p>five</p> </td> <td> <p>six</p> </td>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <td> <p>seven</p> </td> <td> <p>eight</p> </td> <td> <p>nine</p> </td>
    </tfoot>
  </table>      
</main>
```

In the above example I'm using a CSS checkbox to swap the display of 2 tables to simulate changing the styles of one table.

My question is how can I animate those styles during the swap without JavaScript? Is there a way to trigger opacity or ( any ) animation with a checkbox in CSS? I can animate the checkbox itself but how can I fade from one table to another using this technique. Or is it even possible without JS?

**Edit**: The query selector in the beginning is simply to add more CSS styles without using more space in the CSS pane for readability. I'm asking can this be done without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector( 'style' ).innerHTML +=`
  #clear thead p {
    color: #444;
  }
  th:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  }
  th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
  }
  td, p {
    color: #555; cursor: default;
  }
  tr:hover td {
    border-color: #eee;
  }
  tfoot td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  }
  tfoot td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
  }
  tr p:hover {
    color: #000;
  }
  [ for="tog" ], [ for="tog" ]::after {
    position: relative; display: block;
    width: 7rem; height: 4rem;
    margin: 1rem; background-color: #ddd; border-radius: 4rem; content: "";
    cursor: pointer; transition-property: left, background-color;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
  }
`
```

```css
html { overflow: hidden; font-size: 5.5vmin; }
.tog_wrap { position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 1rem; left: 1rem; }
html, table, caption, th, td, p {
  margin: 0; padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom-style: solid; border-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: #fbfbfb; color: #444;
  text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;
  border-spacing: 0; transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;  
}
html, table, caption, caption p, thead, thead p, td p {
  border-style: none; background-color: transparent;
}
html {
  font-family: Arial;
}
[ type="checkbox" ] {
  display: none;
}
table {
  width: 100%; max-width: 40rem; position: relative; top: -2rem;
  margin: 1rem auto; user-select: none;
}
caption p, thead th, thead p {
  border-style: none; background-color: #f7f7f7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
caption, caption p {
  padding: 0 1rem; 
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
}
```

```html
<style>
  [ for="tog" ]:hover { background-color: #ccc; }
  [ for="tog" ]::after {
    position: absolute; left: 0;
    transform: scale( 0.7 ); margin: 0;
    width: 4rem; background-color: #eee;
  }
  #tog:checked ~ main [ for="tog" ]::after { left: 3rem; background-color: #ddd; }
  #tog:checked ~ main [ for="tog" ] { background-color: #444; }
  #tog:checked ~ main [ for="tog" ]:hover { background-color: #333; }
  #tog:checked ~ main #clear th, #tog:checked ~ main #clear th p { 
  background-color: #222; color: #f5f5f5; 
  }
  #tog:checked ~ main #clear tfoot td { background-color: #f5f5f5; }
</style>
<input type="checkbox" id="tog">
<main>
  <div class="tog_wrap"> <label for="tog"></label> </div>
  <table id="clear">
    <caption> <p> table </p> </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> <p>one</p> </th> <th> <p>two</p> </th> <th> <p>three</p> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td> <p>four</p> </td> <td> <p>five</p> </td> <td> <p>six</p> </td>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <td> <p>seven</p> </td> <td> <p>eight</p> </td> <td> <p>nine</p> </td>
    </tfoot>
  </table>     
</main>
```